# EF Core "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column" although IDENTIY_INSERT is set to ON

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework Core 2.1 and want to Insert some Data using IDENTITY_INSERT.
Although I'm setting IDENTITY_INSERT to On, i still get an exception on the line `identityContext.SaveChanges();`:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred
>   while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.'
>
> Inner Exception
>
> SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for
>   identity column in table 'ClientGroups' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to
>   OFF.

This is my code:

```
using (var identityContext = new IdentityDatabase(identityOptions))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Settings Identity Insert on");
    identityContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.ClientGroups ON");
    identityContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Clients ON");
    identityContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.ModulePermissions ON");
    identityContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Roles ON");
    identityContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Users ON");

    identityContext.Clients.AddRange(identityclients);
    identityContext.ClientGroups.AddRange(identityClientGroups);
    identityContext.ClientGroupAssociations.AddRange(identityClientGroupAssociations);
    identityContext.AuthClients.AddRange(identityAuthClients);
    identityContext.Roles.AddRange(identityRoles);
    identityContext.Users.AddRange(identityUsers);
    identityContext.UserRoles.AddRange(identityUserRoles);
    identityContext.ModulePermissions.AddRange(identityModulePermissions);
    Console.WriteLine("Saving Data to .identity Database");
    identityContext.SaveChanges();

    Console.WriteLine("Setting Identity Insert off");
    identityContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.ClientGroups OFF");
    identityContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Clients OFF");
    identityContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.ModulePermissions OFF");
    identityContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Roles OFF");
    identityContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Users OFF");
}
```

I turned logging on and can see that the command was sent to the databse:

> info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
>         Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>         SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.ClientGroups ON info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
>         Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>         SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Clients ON info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
>         Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>         SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.ModulePermissions ON info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
>         Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>         SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Roles ON info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
>         Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>         SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Users ON

Comment: Are your tables really named this way in sql-server?

Comment: [`SET IDENTITY_INSERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): "At any time, only one table in a session can have the IDENTITY_INSERT property set to ON. If a table already has this property set to ON, and a SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON statement is issued for another table, SQL Server returns an error message that states SET IDENTITY_INSERT is already ON and reports the table it is set ON for.". Your code cannot work as written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a mix of the comment of @damien-the-unbeliever and the suggested answer of @ivan stoev

1. You can only have IDENTITY_INSERT turned ON for one table at a time
2. The code must be wrapped in a transaction because EF Core will use separate connections otherwise.

Here is the code

```
using (var identityContext = new IdentityDatabase(identityOptions))
{
    using (var transaction = identityContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inserting AuthClients");
        identityContext.AuthClients.AddRange(identityAuthClients);
        identityContext.SaveChanges();

        Console.WriteLine("Inserting ClientGroups");
        identityContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.ClientGroups ON");
        identityContext.ClientGroups.AddRange(identityClientGroups);
        identityContext.SaveChanges();
        identityContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.ClientGroups OFF");

        Console.WriteLine("Inserting Clients");
        identityContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Clients ON");
        identityContext.Clients.AddRange(identityclients);
        identityContext.SaveChanges();
        identityContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Clients OFF");

        Console.WriteLine("Inserting ClientGroupAssociations");
        identityContext.ClientGroupAssociations.AddRange(identityClientGroupAssociations);
        identityContext.SaveChanges();

        Console.WriteLine("Inserting Users");
        identityContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Users ON");
        identityContext.Users.AddRange(identityUsers);
        identityContext.SaveChanges();
        identityContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Users OFF");

        Console.WriteLine("Inserting Roles");
        identityContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Roles ON");
        identityContext.Roles.AddRange(identityRoles);
        identityContext.SaveChanges();
        identityContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Roles OFF");

        Console.WriteLine("Inserting UserRoles");
        identityContext.UserRoles.AddRange(identityUserRoles);
        identityContext.SaveChanges();

        Console.WriteLine("Inserting ModulePermissions");
        identityContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.ModulePermissions ON");
        identityContext.ModulePermissions.AddRange(identityModulePermissions);
        identityContext.SaveChanges();
        identityContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.ModulePermissions OFF");

        Console.WriteLine("Commiting transaction");
        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

EF Core opens / closes the connection for each database related operation, so setting the identity on with `ExecuteSqlCommand` has no effect.

You need to either explicitly keep the connection opened during the whole process:

```
identityContext.Database.OpenConnection();
try
{
    // your code …
}    
finally
{
    identityContext.Database.CloseConnection();
}
```

or wrap the whole process in explicit transaction:

```
using (var transaction = identityContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    // your code …
    transaction.Commit();
}
```